# ConstraintLayout does not get constrained to bottom when lower subviwe gets hidden

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I tried to make the title as descriptive as possible. 
I have a `ConstraintLayout` with two `LinearLayout` children that have `ScrollView`s inside as there are a lot of stuff inside. Each child has a weight of 1. The layout has constraints to top of toolbar, bottom, left and right to parent and a margin to top. So basically, this layout acts as a bottom sheet that slides up and down. 
Both sub-views (`LinearLayouts`-s) can be "expanded", in which case, the other sub-view changes its visibility to `gone`.

So what happens is when I expand one layout and hide another, for some reason, the whole layout's alignment stays to top of the parent, preserving the margin, but gets cut to the bottom, leaving an empty space. I want it to move to the bottom of the screen is such case. I have also added `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"`, which I thought would take care of it. But it does not work. I will attach pictures.

So what I am trying to achieve is to make the sheet to get aligned bottom all the time. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?ord_canvas_secondary_color">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">

        <include layout="@layout/merge_screen_container" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/dim_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@color/ord_black"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />

    <FilterSheet
        android:id="@+id/subscriptions_filter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dim_8x"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim_56x"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dim_8x"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dim_8x"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"

remove this line and try once.

Comment: Yeah, quite logical. But in that case the sheet goes beyond toolbar. I forgot to mention that the sheet has scroll views insed for each linearlayout. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Also pls post your full xml file code.

Comment: @Artipatel Posted full XML.

Answer (score 2):

This should work. Please try.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?ord_canvas_secondary_color">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">

        <include layout="@layout/merge_screen_container" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/dim_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@color/ord_black"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" >
        <FilterSheet
            android:id="@+id/subscriptions_filter"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dim_8x"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim_56x"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dim_8x"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dim_8x"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?ord_canvas_secondary_color">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">

        <include layout="@layout/merge_screen_container" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/dim_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@color/ord_black"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />

    <FilterSheet
        android:id="@+id/subscriptions_filter"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dim_8x"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim_56x"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dim_8x"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dim_8x"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Same behavior. Maybe I should use `RelativeLayout` for this after all.

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer from @Arti Patel kinda worked, but the filter view would still go beyond toolbar. I ended up using LinearLayout and FrameLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?ord_canvas_secondary_color"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <include layout="@layout/merge_screen_container" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/dim_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@color/ord_black"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <FilterSheet
        android:id="@+id/subscriptions_filter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dim_8x"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/filter_margin_top"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dim_8x"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dim_8x"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</FrameLayout>
```